# Accessing Desktop Folder through the terminal

Tags: bash, macos

I have my xcode Project saved as "GAT App" in a folder on my Desktop. When I try to access the folder using the terminal, this is the error I get:

```
Austins-MacBook-Air:~ austin$ cd Desktop
Austins-MacBook-Air:Desktop austin$ cd GAT App
-bash: cd: GAT: No such file or directory
```

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By typing

```
cd GAT\ App
```

The `\` tells the system that the next whitespace does not separate two arguments but is just one string.